# Creating basins of attraction from data file

Tags: gnuplot, fractals, newtons-method, convergence

How can Newton's basin of attraction be created from a data file?

I got 10000 points in the range -2, 2 and their zeros for complex function z^3-1. I'd like to plot them with three different colors to create basin of convergence.

Data I've obtained from my program is available [here](http://pastebin.com/L96ta3y2). The format is like this:

```
(-0.422468,1.36075) (-0.5,0.866025)
(1.19376,1.1324) (1,-6.76273e-19)
...
```

First two numbers in "( )" are complex start points, the second two are the zero that it converges to. Zeros are exact to the level of e-10, I can easily change it to e-16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, I would try something like:

```
plot 'yourdata.dat' using 1:2:(arg($3+$4*{0,1})) '(%lf,%lf) (%lf,%lf)' palette
```

The string `'(%lf,%lf) (%lf,%lf)'` is the format of your data, so that gnuplot can read it as a file of four columns. Then, you can select the columns to be plotted with `using 1:2:(arg(...))`; in this case, the x-axis is the real part of the starting points (column 1), and the y-axis is its imaginary part (column 2). The third part of using, `arg($3+$4*{0,1})`, and the option `palette` are used to chose the color depending on the phase of the complex zero (columns $3 and $4).

Comment: I have never seen that trick for stating the data file format in the plot command like that, and I thought that I knew gnuplot pretty well.  Is that documented in the gnuplot documention somewhere?  That is remarkable that it can be done that way.

Comment: You are the boss vagoberto, it's so much appreciated, working like a charm!